# LED's brightness difference in these 2 circuits

Tags: voltage, led, inverter, kirchhoffs-laws

I have past exam's problem as follows. Suppose there are circuit A (left image) and B (right image). The question is why LED in circuit A is brighter than in B. The solution states that the Low-level output current (20 mA) is much higher than High-level output current (1 mA). Hence, the LED in A is supplied with proper current. What I do not understand is how one can arrive at this conclusion using Kirchhoff's law and determine the brightness using voltage drop. I also want to know better about these current parameters by doing so.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgOBob.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Bla, bla, circuit, bla. Sorry but my text-to-schematic converter is still broken. Please include a schematic. Edit your question and add a schematic, there's a button that will start a nice schematic entry tool.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Ah. But I did write an LTSpice schematic to ASCII text converter. So at least you can go the other direction!! Hehe. (I should show some example outputs here, someday.) But good point, just the same.

Comment: I have edited the question and also put the schematics

Comment: That look wrong.  Almost no current will flow through the LED in A.

Comment: And almost no current through LED in B as NOT gate outputs low. Maybe this is an actual question - what current is higher - at input or at low output? Without NOT gate specifications impossible to say!

Comment: Inverters aren't atomic components, nor are they all the same. To analyse these circuits we need either internal schematics of the inverter, or equivalent circuits using current or voltage sources.

Comment: Sorry for my careless mistake. I made schematic change for circuit A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would depend on the device used as the inverting gate.

As the answer states:

> The Low-level output current (20 mA) is much higher than High-level output current (1 mA)

One can deduce the inverting gate IC can sink 20mA to GND but can only source 1mA on its "high" state, thus limiting the current on the LED.

It is fairly common for chip to be able to sink more current than sourcing, due to transistor configuration.

Overall this is totally depends of the IC chosen, and there is no part number given.

Comment: It is 74LS04 ttl IC

Comment: @GerryDunda All these information should be automatically in your original question! Everybody has to dig information from you. That's sub-optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the NOT gate will change 5V to 0V and 0V to 5V, the following happens:

Circuit A: 5V -> resistor -> LED -> 0V <- Not <- 5V which is equal to 5V -> resistor -> LED -> 0V, which is a normal circuit and some current will flow (depending on the forward voltage of led D1).

Circuit B: 5V -> Not -> 0V  -> Resistor -> LED -> 0V, which in principle means no current is flowing at all.

Maybe the NOT component works a bit differently (maybe it changes 5V to 2V, or 0V to 3V or whatever. But anyway, in circuit A you probably have more voltage difference than in circuit B, and taking the forward voltage in account, I would expect circuit A to act with a normal current flow, and circuit B not at all.

Comment: It seems circuit B has input low, not high. OP can not stick to the correct circuit diagram constantly changing it.

Comment: Yes, I would swear there was a 5V symbol instead of ground before.